# Changing value of element in Array and pasting result to a named range

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic, range, paste

I am automating a process for my work and am trying to address some issues that will occur in the future. Part of my process is to import different spreadsheets, look for employee names and then find out who their manager is. The problem I am faced with is that people are known as different names on different systems. For example, somebody named "Donald Donaldson" may be called "Don Donaldson" on the System, but has his full name on the employee list. Alternatively, Dave Davidison is David Davidson on the system.

This occurs a number of times (as some people appear 2 times on the System list) and will slow down the entire process while my colleagues manually fix the issues. To address this, I created 3 tables/Dynamic Named Ranges on my Data Tab. Each table (sample found below) had a different purpose; a list of wrong names ("names"), a list of replacement names ("Rep") and alist of the names extracted from the System ("Compare"). I want to look through the Compare list to see if there are any instances of "names" appearing. If it finds an instance then it will replace the name with the correct one

I feel that I am very close to achieving what needs done, but I lack that moment of brilliance to help me burst through.

***My Approach***

I have 3 Dynamic Named Ranges (range length will change depending on what is extracted from the other files) and I have stored them as 3 dynamic arrays (for that very reason). My code is looping through each element in Names, each in Rep and each in Compare. If the value in Compare (z) is equal to the value in Names (x) then we change the value of it to what is in Rep (so z = y) The problem with that is that only the value of z changes, and not the corresponding value in my array. i.e. Don Donaldson is the 3rd element in Compare. I find a match so Z changed from Don Donaldson to Donald Donaldson. Compare(3), however, remains Don Donaldson.

I have tried making a 4th dynamic array, and and using ReDim to increase the length of it with every iteration. With every match myArr(index) is equal to y, and after the loop a 4th named range ("TestRange") is set to the value of this array, this approach does not work either.

Is anyone able to help me? How do I change the value of an element in an Array (compare) and also how do I output this new array to a named range?

My Code and a sample of my data is shown below.

Pleas help. Thanks

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Arr = Worksheets("Data").Range("Names").Value
    Dim comArr() As Variant
    comArr = Worksheets("Data").Range("Compare").Value
    Dim repArr() As Variant
    repArr = Worksheets("Data").Range("Rep").Value
    Dim comInt As Integer
    comInt = 0
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim ArrayCounter As Long

    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim z As Variant
    Dim zInt As Integer
    zInt = 0
    Dim myArr() As Variant

    For Each x In Arr
        For Each y In repArr
            For Each z In comArr
                'ReDim myArr(0 To zInt) As Variant
                If z = x Then
                    z = y
                    'myArr(zInt) = y
                End If
                zInt = zInt + 1
            Next z
        Next y
    Next x

    'Worksheets("Data").Range("TestRange").Value = comArr()
    'Worksheets("Data").Range("TestRange").Value = myArr()
End Sub
```

***My Named Ranges**
*Sorry for the messy layout*

**"Names"**
Don Donaldson,
David Davidson,
Mike Michaels,
Pat Paterson,
Steve Stevenson,
Jack Jackson,
Robert Robertson,
Harvey Harvie,
John Johnson

**"Rep"** 
Donald Donaldson,
Dave Davidson,
Michael Michaels,
Patrick Paterson,
Steven Stephenson, 
Jak Jackson,
Rob Robertson,
Harv Harvie,
Jon Johnson

**"Compare"**
Don Donaldson,
Mike Michaels,
Jack Jackson,
John Johnson,
Pat Paterson,
Percy Perkins,
Don Donaldson,
Tom Thomson,
Harvey Harvie,
Mark Marcus,
Kris Kristofferson,
Mitch Mitchell,
Jack Jackson,
Rob Robertson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said I managed to gather another solution to this problem, however it doesn't use Arrays or named ranges. The code is below

```
Sub RangesArrays()

    Dim FoundOne As Range, extractNames As Range, exceptionNames As Range, c As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


   'This is the Compare list
    Worksheets("ExtractSheet").Activate
    Set extractNames = Worksheets("ExtractSheet").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    'This is the Names
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    Set exceptionNames = Worksheets("Data").Range(Range("D1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


    'Loops through names list. C is an element
    For Each c In exceptionNames
        With extractNames
            'This looks for c
            Set FoundOne = .Find(What:=c, LookAt:=xlPart)
            If Not FoundOne Is Nothing Then
                'If there is a match then it looks to replace the current name with the     replacement
                'name. What is FoundOne, and replacement is what is on the cell directly     to the lsit
                'name.offset(0 on x, 1 on y)
                extractNames.Replace What:=FoundOne, Replacement:=c.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
            End If
        End With
    Next c
    'Reset values to default
    Set extractNames = Nothing: Set exceptionNames = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but it's too long and I'd like to provide some code for you.

I think the logic of your code is wrong... (Pseudocode)

```
if z(Don Donaldson) = x(Don Donaldson) >> myArr(?) = Don Donaldson
```

and there are 55 situation which match such comparison. But you are not able to check which is corresponding element in `y(Donald Donaldson)`. To do so you either need to have any parameter which match to each array (element) or you need to use any `key index` which is not available here. Moreover,  there are different number of elements in each of array. In my opinion you could solve it only with manual work with such set of data you have.

The check partially what I suggest try to change internal part of your loop to this code:

```
'...your code here
        For Each z In comArr

            If z = x Then
                ReDim Preserve myArr(zInt) As Variant
                z = y
                myArr(zInt) = y
                zInt = zInt + 1
            End If

        Next z
'your code here
```

If you additionally change last commented  line into this and uncomment it to see results:

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("TestRange").Value = Application.Transpose(myArr)
```

Comment: KazJaw, 

Thanks for your input. I tried your suggested solution and it pasting the contents of myArr multiple times. The contents of myArr is also the same as Arr so I am not sure how I woiuld fix this.

I have come across another solution that solves my problem. It works in a similar manner, but doesn't use arrays or named ranges.